# Can I install a Mac-like taskbar?

Tags: unity, taskbar

I read somewhere that you can use a taskbar like the one in Mac. I have problems with adapting to the Unity launcher. Can someone please help me with this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try installing the Cairo dock which looks like the equivalent of the launcher in Mac. All you have to do is that you have to boot into Ubuntu, open the terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). Then give the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cairo-dock-team/ppa` to install the PPA and then give the command `sudo apt-get update`. Then install Cairo-dock via the command: `sudo apt-get install cairo-dock cairo-dock-plug-ins`. It should do the job.